# How to integrate Laravel API and VueJs project to a single URL/Project?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, integration

I have an API created using Laravel and can be accessed through the URL: http://www.project.com/api using the virtual host in which http://www.project.com/ points to the public folder of the Laravel project. I also have a separate Vue project created using Vue CLI which connects and request data to the Laravel API and can be accessed through http://localhost:8080/.

My question is, can I integrate the 2 separate projects into a single project or URL and if yes, how?

Comment: this is called using nginx as a proxy. Read about upstream services in NGINX - generally it means have a / location that points to your VueJS nodejs server, and /api which gets routed to your PHP project

Comment: Here's an article that uses docker (but can pretty easily be rewritten to just support vanilla PHP) https://medium.com/@francoisromain/setup-node-js-apache-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-docker-1f5a5cb3e71e

Comment: Just put your vue-project in the public folder?

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for your reply. I will try your suggestions as soon as I get back home.

Comment: Did you solve this?. I have the same requirement

Comment: @Trent can you give me an example of how to do it?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Laravel come out of the box with Laravel Mix which you can use for compiling your Vue project and serve it through Laravel.

Here are steps to do it.

1. First you copy whole Vue project to `/resources/render` (you can change `render` to anything you like).
2. Go to your Laravel root folder and open up file named `webpack.mix.js` and change it to like this

   ```
   const mix = require('laravel-mix');

   // Assuming your Vue entry point is index.js
   mix.js('resources/render/index.js', 'public/js');
   ```
3. Create a blade file as entry point in `resources/views`. In my case it's `main.blade.php`.

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Laravel</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="app">
       {{-- Content --}}
     </div>
   </body>
   <script type="application/javascript" src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
   </html>
   ```
4. Go to your `routes/web.php` and put only this route in. It will handles all routes in your Vue app

   ```
   Route::get('{path}', function () {
     return view('index');
   })->where('path', '^(.+)?$');
   ```
5. Run `npm install` and `npm run watch` to build and react to changes you make to your Vue app. (You might want to remove unwanted dependencies from `package.json`)

I have a similar project with this setup. You can see it [here](https://github.com/ninja-stack/a-zhare) for better understanding